# Undefined method for nil:NilClass in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am rendering a list of posts, each of which are associated with the user who posted them. Some users have avatars, some don't.

Here is the view code:

```
 <% if @posts.exists? %>
  <ul class="forum-activity-list">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li class="forum-activity-item">
      <div class="item-photo">
        <%= render 'users/avatar', user: post.user %>
      </div>
      <div class="item-info">
        <%= link_to post.title, post_path(post), :class => "title" %>
        <div class="metadata">Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by <%= post.user.email %> in Advertising</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-replies">
        <span><%= post.comments.count %></span> replies
      </div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
```

This bit renders the avatar through a partial:

```
<%= render users/avatar, user: post.user %>
```

And here is the partial:

```
<% if user.avatar.presence %>
 <%= image_tag user.avatar.url %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to user_path(user), :class => "default-profile-image" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Locally, this works fine and as expected. But in production, I get this error in my logs: "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass)"

In production, there are no posts, so I would expect to not have any render (and thus not get this issue), but it's still happening.

Any idea why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you add a post to production does it prevent the error? Can you clear out all posts locally to see if you get the error then? Please post the entire error log. Seeing what is happening before and after the error are a huge part of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production you have a post that doesn't have an associated user. Perhaps the user was deleted after the post was created.

Comment: I should also point out that it's almost always better to make sure your data is clean, and trust the data in the code you write, than it is to sprinkle defensive code all over the place, which distracts from your business logic and makes refactoring more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have faced similar issues before, this is because in some point you modified your database schema and you have old data in production that is giving you problems, if your production app is not in use by real users and if you do not have important data do the following in the terminal of your deployed server:

This will remove your database, create it again and reload your current schema with all:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

and if you have seeds.rb with test data you can also run

```
rake db:seed
```

All data will be lost, if you cannot remove current data, you will need to look manually for each post and delete that one that does not have associated user.

Comment: Thansk! however I will create another question asking how to do it, when app is deployed for example in heroku

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in this line `<% if user.avatar.presence %>`

[***presence***](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) returns the receiver if it’s present otherwise returns ***nil***. `object.presence` is equivalent to

```
object.present? ? object : nil
```

You should use [***present?***](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) instead

```
<% if user.avatar.present? %>
 <%= image_tag user.avatar.url %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to user_path(user), :class => "default-profile-image" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```